# How can I measure the size of a webpage?

Tags: images, compression, file-size

I'm building a website at the moment that has several complicated background images and repeats. The file sizes for each of the images are quite large (I've compressed them down as much as possible!), is there an online tool that I can use to measure the filesize of a page?

Comment: Are you specifically looking for an *on-line* tool? This is generally done in the browser.

Comment: @Su' It doesn't really matter how, just need to analyse a page to see how big it is. If that means adding an extension to chrome, pasting a link into some tool or whatever. As long as it's accurate!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Download [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) and install [Google's Page Speed](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/download.html) plugin and or Yahoo!'s [YSlow](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/yslow/?src=search) plugin both of these will help you optimise around the background image.

Also read Yahoo's [Best Practices for Speeding Up Your Website](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html)

Comment: I'm ok what to compress and where, I just want to see how big the page total is.

Comment: YSlow will show you that along with the total load time in milliseconds: http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/help/views.html#stats_view

Answer (score 3):

I found [this](http://www.websiteoptimization.com/services/analyze/) from searching for a couple of minutes, looks like it may do the trick for you!

Comment: Seemed to do the trick. Eeeessshhhh 1.7mb for my page - I better get compressing!

Comment: Let us know what you manage to get it down to. :-)

Comment: I just tried yslow, seems a bit easier as I don't have to go to another website website as it's a chrome extension. Thanks  for the site though.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>I don't know of any online tools personally, though if it were me I would just select your image folder(s) and html, js, stylesheet files and look at the collective filesize that way.</strike>

There is always the page speed addon for Firefox/Chrome that will give you recommendations for other optimizations you can do to improve the speed of your site.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The first part of this would give the total size of combined files for an entire *site*, including things that may not even be getting used, not the size per-page.

Comment: True, don't know why I didn't think of that. :s

Comment: @Anonymous- I'm fine with how and what to compress, just need to know the total page filesize, surely there's a way to see it without manually counting?

Answer (score 1):

The [Web Developer Toolbar](http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/) for Firefox has a "View Document Size" item under the Information menu. (This option is missing in the Chrome version, for some reason.) It opens a tab that shows you overall size, broken down by section(images, scripts, stylesheets, etc) which you can toggle open for a detailed listing, in case you need to hunt down a particular item that's a problem.

Comment: I just got the extension but I guess it's not included in the newest version as there's no "View Document Size" option.

Comment: Huh. It *is* missing in the Chrome version.